# Android: opening and closing SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm developing and android application in which I often use access the local database. This database can be accessed from differents therads, so I have a coordination problem for the database. I use the following `open()` and `close()` method.

```
public void open(){ 
    mDb=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){
        mDb.close();
}
```

So, usually, when I need to access the db for some operations I open the database, then I perform some operation, and finally I close the database. The code I typically use for this purpose is the following:

```
    try {
        dbManager.open();
                    // database operation
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            dbManager.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But, if for this piece of code is used from differnts threads (supposing thread A and thread B) the following situation may occurs:

```
A thread: performs open()
B thread: perfroms open()
A thread: perfroms some operation
A thread: performs close()
B thread: try to perform some operation but it fails!
```

So, the only solution I can guess I to perform `open()` when my application starts and `close()` when my application is stopped. I'm not sure that this can be this a good solution?

In effect, the documentation of `getWritableDatabase()` method (called from my `open()`) says:

```
Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database
```

So, anyone can suggest me an alternative solution?

Comment: don't close db, just close only the cursor to that data

Comment: synchronize access or do db ops on one thread only

Comment: ... or build ContentProvider ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the singletone instance and gennerally you can do not close database (but keep transaction closed). There is some information:

[Android SQLite DB When to Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557154/android-sqlite-db-when-to-close)

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper class, add an atomic integer member and every time you open the database, increment the member, when you close it, decrement the member and if the member is zero, actually close the db.

Comment: no, you will have an atomic integer to know when to really close the db and you will call close on wrapper and inside the wrapper, only if that int is 0 you will actually close the db