# opening and closing a sqlite database after using it everytime

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is it a good practice to open and close the database for every database transaction operation? let me clear you more.

I have two methods like

```
public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
    if (database == null || !database.isOpen()) {
        database = getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return database;
}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
        database.close();
    }
}
```

so every time, when I am updating/inserting or deleting, I am opening the database and closing it.

```
 public void insert(...) {
      getDatabase().insert(...);
      closeDatabase();
 }

 public void update(...) {
      getDatabase().update(...);
      closeDatabase();
 }

 public void delete(...) {
      getDatabase().delete(...);
      closeDatabase();
 }
```

remember that all these methods are inside a class `DatabaseHelper` which is extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` and there is a global variable `private SQLiteDatabase database`

and I will perform these operations(insert/update/delete) more frequently.

So my question is `Is it a good practice to open and close database for every transaction? if not, what is the good way? Where and When I have to close my database?`

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608498/best-place-to-close-database-connection

Comment: I always let the db open only for the strict necessary time to consume my data out of it or modify data into it. And close it immediately after.

Answer (score 2):

Opening and closing the database every time may (un-intentionally) run into problem such as `Trying to open an already closed database`.

Hence, I would suggest is to have a Singleton for the creating the database object, so that every time you make a call to `database = getWritableDatabase();` you refer to the same object.

Consider closing this in onDestroy() method, so that as and when the App closes database is closed too.

```
private static AllItemsDB db; //AllItemsDB is my database class
public static AllItemsDB getDb() {

    if (db == null) {
        Log.d("","Issue here");
        db = new AllItemsDB(app);
        Log.d("","Issue here not");
    }

    return db;
}
```

since this is a static method, I can do AllItemsDB.myCRUD_methods and it will return me the same oblect every time and easy to access as well. :)

[Help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557154/android-sqlite-db-when-to-close)

Comment: Thats another question ;-)