# SqliteDatabase and Orientation change

Tags: android

Hello i am using SqliteDatabase and i am using a background service to download some data. I have the db to closed onDestroy() method and to open onCreate() and onResume(). When i change the orientation of the phone some times the background service try to save the data into the database when the db is closed because of the orientation change. How i can fix that?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyApplication.getInstance().openDatabase();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.getInstance().openDatabase();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MyApplication.getInstance().closeDatabase();
}
```

This is some of the code of my MainActivity. I have the database to MyApplication class. The service just using MyApplication.getInstance().insert(data); that is insert data into the db. Can i close the database only when the app is closed and not on the orientation change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557154/android-sqlite-db-when-to-close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close db on onDestroy() of the service

Comment: i want the database open because i will do some other staffs, and closed only when the app is closed

Comment: and when does the application class get destroyed?