# Adding values into DataPoint array causing the application crash while running

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am using `GraphView` library code which contains `DataPoint[]` Array.
My code also contains a database named `olddb` which I use to insert the array length in the code below.
The first 2 `for` loops are for adding the values in the database into an array and the third for loop is to get the values out from the arrays `arrayWeight` and `arrayId` and add them to `DataPoint[]` array.

Though something seems to go wrong, after I run the program it just crashes, can anyone figure out what is causing the application to crash?

```
private DataPoint[] getDataPoint() {
        if (olddb.check()) {
            List<oldDetails> details = olddb.getDetails();
            double[] arrayWeight = new double[olddb.getDetailsCount()];
            int[] arrayId = new int[olddb.getDetailsCount()];
            for (oldDetails cn : details) { //Adding weights and id of all time to an array.
                double num = cn.getWeight();
                int id = cn.getId();
                for (int i = arrayWeight.length; i > 0; i--) {
                    arrayWeight[i] = num;
                    arrayId[i] = id;
                }
            }
            DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[olddb.getDetailsCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayId.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayWeight.length; j++)
                    dp[i] = new DataPoint(i, arrayWeight[j]);
            }

            return dp;
        }
        else {
            DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[]{
                    new DataPoint(0, 0)
            };
            return dp;
        }
    }
```

Here is an example for working code of `DataPoint` array:

```
private DataPoint[] getDataPoint(){
    DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[]{
                new DataPoint(0,1),
                new DataPoint(2,5),
                new DataPoint(5,5),
                new DataPoint(7,4)
    };
    return dp;
}
```

EDIT:
here is the error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.none.myapplication, PID: 3881
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.none.myapplication/com.none.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT  * FROM oldDetails
```

[Database](http://codeshare.io/5Obd72)

Comment: it will tell you in LogCat what the crash is, learn to read it: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: @Blundell I found a message finally https://codeshare.io/2EzBo5 I really don't understand what is the problem

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT  * FROM oldDetails` is the error, which happens inside of `DatabaseHandlerOld.getDetailsCount` line 141

Comment: @Blundell do you find anything wrong here? https://codeshare.io/5RkbWa

Comment: yes, you must close your database connection inside of `DatabaseHandlerOld.getDetailsCount` but inside `getDataPoint()` you call this method twice, therefore it crashes

Comment: @Blundell So I should add it into variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some researches and some of Blundell help, I figured out the problem was indeed the close(); method in my database.
Though the solution was to change the getDetailsCount() function to this:

```
public long QueryNumEntries()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_OLDDETAILS);
}
```

and in my main activity file:

```
private DataPoint[] getDataPoint() {
        if (olddb.check()) {
            List<oldDetails> details = olddb.getDetails();
            long c = olddb.QueryNumEntries();
            int count = (int) c;
            Log.d("Count", "equals: " + count);

        double[] arrayWeight = new double[count];
        int[] arrayId = new int[count];
        for (oldDetails cn : details) { //Adding weights and id of all time to an array.
            double num = cn.getWeight();
            int id = cn.getId();
            Log.d("num", "equals: " + num);
            Log.d("id", "equals: " + id);
            for (int i = count; i < 0; i--) {
                arrayWeight[i] = num;
                arrayId[i] = id;
            }
        }
        DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayId.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayWeight.length; j++) {
                dp[i] = new DataPoint(arrayId[i], arrayWeight[j]);
                Log.d("ArrayWeight", "equals: " + arrayWeight[j]);
                Log.d("ArrayId", "equals: " + arrayId[i]);
            }
        }

        return dp;
    }

        DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[]{
                new DataPoint(0, 0)
        };
        return dp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by replacing all 3 calls to `olddb.getDetailsCount()`

with

`int count = olddb.getDetailsCount();`

then:

```
double[] arrayWeight = new double[count];
int[] arrayId = new int[count];
DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[count];
```

However you need to understand the issue:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM oldDetails` is the error, which happens inside of `DatabaseHandlerOld.getDetailsCount` line 141

[Android SQLite DB When to Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557154/android-sqlite-db-when-to-close)

Comment: After doing the changes you've told me it still crashes with this error message. https://codeshare.io/5Xj8nG

Comment: perhaps you close the database connection inside of the `check()` method? you should not do this